# How to get longitude and latitude to display correct in print layout?

Tags: qgis

This is what I have so far:
[image: This is what I have so far.]

My goal is to have the longitude and latitude grid lines and labels to display correctly...obviously 0-20 would not be correct labels. All my project layers were reprojected into an Albers projection, so I selected that same map projection when adding the gridlines.

This is what the final product should look like:

[image: This is what the final gridlines should look like.]

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have selected `Centimeter` as your unit instead of `Map Unit` for your interval. Also if your map is in a projected CRS but you want to label it in degrees you will need to set the CRS of your **grid** to EPSG:4326.

[image]

Which gives me the following:

[image]